# Install4j Not delete file

Tags: install4j

I have such action before install files:
[image]

I want to delete all jar files in app (if such are available)
As result jar files don't delete.
In logs:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.DeleteFileAction [ID 270]: Execute action
       Property directoryFilter: null
       Property fileFilter: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_115
       Property files: [.]
       Property filesRoot: null
       Property backupForRollback: false
       Property recursive: false
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Property showFileNames: true
       Property showProgress: false
       Execute action successful after 2 ms
```

P.S. Tested on Linux. Try to obtain max privileges is on for Linux build.

Comment: Are these JAR files maybe in a subdirectory? You would have to select the "Recursive" option in that case.

Comment: No, my JAR in root directory. "Recursive" option didn't help.